# Make user name bolded in text in PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
$text = 'Hello @demo here!';
$pattern = '/@(.*?)[ ]/';
$replacement = '<strong>${1}</strong> ';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

This works, I get HTML like this: `Hello <strong>demo</strong> here!`. But this not works, when that `@demo` is at the end of string, example: `$text = 'Hello @demo';`. How can I change my pattern, so it will return same output whenever it is end of the string or not.

**Question 2:**

What if the string is like `$text = 'Hello @demo!';`, so it will not put `!` as bolded text? Just catch `space`, `end of string` or `not real-word`.

Sorry for bad English, hope you know what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a word boundary, that's what they're for:

`$pattern = '/@(.+?)\b/';`

This will work for question 2 also

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot, I'll use yours one, looks simplier.

Answer (score 2):

In order to select a word beginning with the @ symbol, this regex will work:

`$pattern = "/@(\w+)\b/"`

`\w` is a short hand character class for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\b` is an anchor for the beginning or end of a word, in this case the end. So the regex is saying: *select something starting with an '@' followed by one or more word characters until the end of the word is reached*.

Reference: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: But need to use `@(\w+)\b`, so it will return matches, but great answer too! (tested here: https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an option to match the end of the string:

```
 @(.*?)(?= |\p{P}?$)
```

Replace with `<strong>$1</strong>`.
You can also use `\p{P}` (any Unicode punctuation symbol) to prevent punctuation from bold formatting.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX2oU4/5).

Comment: Just characters, like `[a-z|A-Z]`, so then it will be `@(.[a-z|A-Z]?)(?: |$)`, right?

Comment: Yes, I realized it now. Look at @rjdown's answer, it work for both questions and also for users with numbers

Comment: Yes, I see. I just want to note that `[a-z|A-Z]` will capture `|` symbol.